# C# - Using WCF for a local network client/server software

Tags: c#, wcf, distributed-computing

I'm working on this project where I have 7 PCs connected to a switch, one of them is the server.

The clients wont send/receive data between each other, they will only send some "characters/strings" to the server. Also, the server will send "characters/strings" to the clients. Also, I need to know on the server software if the clients are connected normally.

So I read that using WCF is the best way of doing this program. Also, I guess it can work normally using `TcpClient` in C#.

So what's the best way for dealing with such case? Any good tutorials or example that can be of help?

Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for help on technology-choice decision. What is the .Net version that you will be able to program against? if you can program against .Net 3.0 or later, you have the option of WCF, else, you don't have that option

Comment: First of all, your question isn't very specific, making it a bad candidate for StackOverflow. Your explanation of "sending characters/strings" is vague. A more detailed explanation of what you're trying to achieve might get a more useful answer, but more importantly, some display of actual effort on your part, like code examples of stuff you've tried. There are a great many ways to send data between computers on a network. All of these ways involve some variation of sending/receiving "characters/strings". Without something a bit more specific about your requirements, it's impossible to advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF is a good solution and allows an easy way for enrich the comunication in the future. You can host the service in any .net project (console application, web prohect, windows forms or wpf). Adding the reference via Visual Studio and use the proxy is straightful and you won't need the TcpClient (actually I don't think it would work).

Your needs seems to be very simple so I suggest you to take a look at the followind web cast:
https://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/EventDetail.aspx?EventID=1032344313&culture=en-US 
The first is more than enough.